# unordered_map emplace - how to create objects in place

Tags: c++, unordered-map

need to create unordered_map for integer and some user defined class - MyClass, where MyClass uses mutex for data access synchronisation, i.e. MyClass object can not be copied or moved.
Is it possible to create such a map?
How do I use emplace to create object of MyClass to avoid copy/move?

```cpp
template<typename T>
class MyClass {
  public:
    T pop() {
      std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
      m_cv.wait(lock, [this]{return !m_queue.empty();});
      return m_queue.pop();
    }
    void push(T const& x) {
      { 
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_queue.push(x) ;
      }
      m_cv.notify_one();
    }
  private:
    std::queue<T> m_queue ;
    std::mutex m_mutex ;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
};

int main(){
  std::unordered_map<int, MyClass<float>> mmap;
  mmap.emplace(1, MyClass<float>{});
}
```

Comment: anyway this code will not compile, as `std::queue::pop` returns void, and not `T`. if `T` is `void`, than `std::queue<void>` is illegal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

```
mmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
             std::forward_as_tuple(1),  // args for key
             std::forward_as_tuple());  // args for mapped value
```

(This uses the piecewise pair constructor for the value type.)

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR:** just use `operator []`, I think it's simpler, like:

```
std::map<int, MyClass<float>> mmap;
auto& obj = mmap[1]; // here it created an object and returned a reference
```

**Details:** I had a similar situation once, here is a link to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42001375/895077) with details.